# CentOS7: rpmbuild - Unable to recognise the format of the input file

Tags: centos7, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm trying to build an extremely simple rpm over centos7.
I just copy some pre-compiled executables from the tar.gz to /usr/bin/my_rpms/rpm1.
Here is my install section:

```
%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/usr/bin/my_rpms/rpm1/
install -D prog prog.o -t %{buildroot}/usr/bin/my_rpms/rpm1/
```

it used to work find for the most part.
but today when after i made some changes to the prog and re-compiled it keeps gettings these errors:

```
+ mkdir -p /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/rpm1.x86_64/usr/bin/my_rpms/rpm1/
+ install -D prog prog.o -t /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/rpm1.x86_64/usr/bin/my_rpms/rpm1/
+ /usr/lib/rpm/check-buildroot
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-compress
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip /usr/bin/strip
/usr/bin/strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `/root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/rpm1.x86_64/usr/bin/drivertest_rpms/rpm1/prog.o'
```

Comment: Sounds like the file is somehow corrupted; does `objdump` recognize it?

Comment: Yes. The files didn't change. I even tried re-building the previous version of this RPM, and it failed the same way.

Comment: And you're not cross-compiling? `file` on it reports the right architecture, etc?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in error log, problem is with binary file striping which is default behavior of `install` command. I think your build environment is maybe different then rpm environment. cross-compiling? as suggested by @aaron-d-marasco

So I recommend to build rpm from project source. i.e move your build commands into `%build` section of .spec file.

Or strip your files in the same place where you have build them, and then in rpm use `cp` command in `%install` section instead of `install` command to move your files to target directory.